# What is the ".phpintel" folder at the top of the Laravel file structure?

Tags: php, git, laravel-5.3

I am just noticing that there is a `.phpintel` folder at the top of the Laravel file structure. Where did it come from, is it necessary and can I `gitignore` it?

Comment: Do you use the Sublime editor? If so, it's a hidden folder from the PHPIntel package (https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PHPIntel) which contains metadata about your project for things like code hinting and class/function auto-suggestions.

Comment: Your correct. Is it ok to gitignore it's files?

Comment: Yes, you should ignore it. Those files have nothing to do with your real code (which is what you want to source control), will repeatedly generate `diff`s and merge conflicts if you do track them in Git, and are useless to anyone else who's not using Sublime with that extension installed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did the ignore and everything is fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ignore any hidden (and generated) data

You will find phpintel ignored in many .gitignore project file, such as:

- [postmark-php/.gitignore](https://github.com/wildbit/postmark-php/blob/master/.gitignore)
- [Zizaco/entrust/.gitignore](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust/blob/master/.gitignore)
- ...

Comment: I'll reinstall it and observe the files in Git and post again. I just don't want too much unnecessary files committed.

Answer (score 6):

`phpintel` is a common sublime plugin. PHP code scanner and analyzer for code intelligence within PHP projects.

It creates **.phpintel** directory like **.idea** for Phpstorm and it should be included to `.gitignore` list of project and contains local project related settings and history for it.